# docker not building a new clean image

Tags: gradle, docker

I am currently trying some examples that allow me to build a docker image, copy a java application in it and run tomcat to access that application on a specific port.
I have been able to achieve this but what I am having difficulty with is committing new changes.
For example, if I make a new change to controller and build the app, when I build docker, it doesn't seem to take those changes into account.

I am using the following tools:
Intellij
Gradle
Dockerfile in the main>docker folder

I run the following commands:

```
gradle build

./gradlew buildDocker
```

The second command runs a task in the gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')

    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'docker'

group = 'springio'


jar {
    baseName = 'gs-serving-web-content'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    push = true
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
    }
}
```

This, subsequently runs the Dockerfile

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

The build is partially unsuccessful

```
> Docker execution failed
  Command line [docker push springio/gs-serving-web-content:latest] returned:
  unauthorized: authentication required
```

However, the image gets created anyway, which I then run using the following command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t springio/gs-serving-web-content
```

The command above runs tomcat and I can access the controller on localhost.

However, as I mentioned earlier, if I make changes to the application and do all the building steps above, changes don't take effect.

PS:
I have tried stopping and starting the container 
I have killed all the containers
I have also delete the image

It looks like docker is caching it maybe?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/):

> For the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the file(s) in the
>   image are examined and a checksum is calculated for each file. The
>   last-modified and last-accessed times of the file(s) are not
>   considered in these checksums. During the cache lookup, the checksum
>   is compared against the checksum in the existing images. If anything
>   has changed in the file(s), such as the contents and metadata, then
>   the cache is invalidated.

If you don't want use the cache at all, you can run docker build with

> --no-cache=true

option, but you don't need it if your local gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar has really been changed before running the new docker build, because the cache should be already invalidated.

If you stop and start the same container, obviously it doesn't get the changes (to your externally built application) done after having built the image, because you must build a new image and start a new container based on it.

So I would double-check that the file gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar really changed in the directory where docker build looks for it.

Comment: I came across that but my understanding is that ADD will add a new image if this is modified, so technically I don't need to activate --no-cache=true as a modified image will be be picked up right?
I am using the commands above to build the jar, how can I validate that my changes have effectively taken place?
I am using gradle build , are there other commands that are needed to create a jar file with new changes?
Thanks